# Canvas resizing using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to resize an canvas listening to the `onresize & onload`-events.

The code that is working quit fine is a mixture between js & jQuery as you can see here:

**How can I translate the full code into jQuery?**

```
window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
  $("canvas")[0].width = $("canvas")[0].offsetWidth;
  $("canvas")[0].height = $("canvas")[0].offsetHeight;
} // this code is working pretty good
```

---

What I've tried so far is not working fine:

```
window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
  $("canvas").width($("canvas").offset().width);
  $("canvas").height($("canvas").offset().height);
} // this code is not working as expected
```

What would be a working approach instead?

Comment: I finished editing my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

<s>`.offset()` has `.top` and `.left`, not `.width` and `.height`</s>

You're actually looking for [`.outerWidth`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) which gives the same result as the native [`.offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth#Example)

```
window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
  $("canvas").width($("canvas").outerWidth());
  $("canvas").height($("canvas").outerHeight());
}
```

or more jQerily

```
function resizeCanvas() {
  $("canvas").width($("canvas").outerWidth());
  $("canvas").height($("canvas").outerHeight());
}
$(function(){
  resizeCanvas()
  $(window).on("resize", resizeCanvas)
})
```

Be aware, that if you are doing this on a page with more than one canvas, you wll give the same size (from the first canvas element matched) to all the canvas elements on the page, as opposed to first-to-first only with the `[0]`

If you want each one to be independent, you should do this instead:

```
function resizeCanvas() {
  $("canvas").each(function(){
    this.width(this.outerWidth())
    this.height(this.outerHeight())
  }
}
$(function(){
  resizeCanvas()
  $(window).on("resize", resizeCanvas)
})
```

This should also improve performance, as the query `"canvas"` is only matched once per invocation.

**Important:** In any case, you should wrap the `"resize"` handler in a debounce function, otherwise the browser will be doing a lot of work for nothing, causing lag. I recommend [the one from `underscore`](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) like this:

```
$(function(){
  resizeCanvas()
  $(window).on("resize", _.debounce(resizeCanvas, 400))
})
```

PS: Why are you using jQuery?

Comment: no offense at all, but to be honest, none of these functions work properly except my own. I can't see why that is so. Still - I'll try again and keep you informed of what the mistake was.

Comment: none taken. Can you tell me what you are trying to achieve with this code? It seems like it would repeatedly set the dimensions to dimensions equal or greater than the existing dimensions, either doing nothing or forever growing the canvas elements. Could you post a JSBin|JSFiddle|Codepen of your minimum example? Finally, please clarify why jQuery is a requirement of the solution, is it browser support?